# ImageMagick: how to compare images in different folders in the bash script

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I have three folders, named - folder1, folder2 and difference. I need to compare an images from folder "folder1" and "folder2" and save the compared image in "difference" folder with name for example diff_namefile1. I have many files in "folder1". All files in "folder1" and "folder2" they have the same names.
I wrote script, but unfortunately it's work.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES1=/Users/user/screenshots/folder1/*png
FILES2=/Users/user/screenshots/folder2/*png

for f in $FILES1
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  compare $FILES1 $FILES2 $f-"diff.png"
done
```

Answer (score 5):

You are pretty close! Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

folder1=/Users/Mark/tmp/1
folder2=/Users/Mark/tmp/2
differences=/Users/Mark/tmp/diff

cd "$folder1"
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.png *.jpg *.gif; do
  file1="$f"
  file2="$folder2/$f" 
  result="$differences/$f-diff.png"
  echo "Comparing $file1 with $file2 => $result"
  compare "$file1" "$file2" "$result"
done
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Unfortunately it doesn't work because script compare file1.png from folder1 with file1.png and file2.png from folder2. I want compare file1.png from folder1 with file1.png from folder2. Next file2.png from folder1 with file2.png from folder2 etc.

Comment: I have updated it - it got mangled when pasting. It is clearer about what it is doing now. Please try again.

Comment: Working as expected. Thank you very much Mark.